Stone's Representation Theorem equivalences
I have seen statements such as "Stone's Representation Theorem is equivalent to Compactness, Tychonoff, Ultrafilter Lemma, Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem, Completeness Theorem.... over ZF"
However i had trouble finding any literature concerning proofs of any of those statements, especially the direction Stone=>...
Would anyone of you be so kind to point tell me where to fond anything about those proofs, or if they are trivial and i just am very confused
Mfg dw

This appears in "The Axiom of Choice" by Jech, as problem 12 in "Problems 2.6". It comes with a hint (we're trying to prove Stone implies BPI): "Let $B$ be a Boolean algebra, $\pi''B = \mathcal F$ an isomorphic set algebra. Let $p \in \bigcup \mathcal F$ and let $U = {u \in B : p \in \pi(u)}$".

thanks for your Help :), I completely forgot to look at the problems in Jech's Book, only flew over the chapter on Boolean Algebras. Thanks.

That the Stone representation theorem implies the ultrafilter lemma is almost immediate: Every set algebra has ultrafilters on it (for any point in the underlying set, take the collection of sets in the algebra containing that point).
And the other way is just the usual proof of the Stone representation theorem, whose only use of the axiom of choice is in showing that the putative embedding $b\mapsto\{U\in S(B): b\in U\}$ of $B$ into $P(S(B))$ is injective. Which follows from the observation that if $b\ne b',$ then either $b\land \lnot b'$ or $b'\land\lnot b $ is nonzero, and so by the ultrafilter lemma, there is an ultrafilter $U$ such that $b\in U$ and $b'\notin U$ or vice versa.
